# OpenCL: Cloo does not see API debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, opencl, intel, cloo

I use a C# wrapper called CLoo to use the OpenCL API. The openCL platform I use is the Intel CPU.

When I run the official Intel sample code (a C/C++ application) then in the VS2010 IntelOpenCL plugin windows (Tools/Cod builder-OpenCL Debugger) I can see the command queue, the API call history etc. So the host side API debugging works. The kernel debugging works too.

When I do the same with CLoo then I can only debug the kernel, but not the host side API. I turned on both the kernel debugging chekcbox (Tools/Code Builder-Options/Basic Settings/Enable OpenCL Kernel Debugging) and also the host side API debugging (Tools/Code Builder-Options/API Debugger/Enable OpenCL API Debuger).

For the Intel C/C++ sample I have seen when I call the first OpenCL API function (clGetPlatformIDs) then a port is opened (56202) by my application and the VS Intel OpenCL plugin connects to it.
I also noticed then the context is create then another port is opened (56203) up by my application and VS connects to it. This must be the kernel debugging port.

My question is when I call the first OpenCL API call (clGetPlatformIDs) with Cloo why does it not open the API debugger port as for the C/C++ application.

As a workaround I have found that one can turn on the logging by using environment variables, but it is not as convenient as VS plugins would be.
INTEL_OCL_DBG_LOG=1
INTEL_OCL_DBG_LOG_FILE=c:\temp\debugger.txt

Comment: Did you find a solution for debugging OpenCL code loaded with CLoo in C#?